# How to draw stacked barplot on the summed data

Tags: r

For data called `df` that reads:

```
car suv pickup
 1   2   1
 2   3   4
 4   1   2
 5   4   2
 3   1   1
```

```
total =  apply(df,1,sum)
barplot(total,col= rainbow(5))
```

So what I did right now is plotting a barplot on total number of cars, which are in fact, the sum of each row. What I want to do now is to present it as a stack barplot on the sum.

For now, it would just show "total" without any lines indicating whether 1 car, 2 suv, 1 pickup addes to 4 "total".

Note. It is different from `barplot(matrix(df))`, because that's just dividing it my car,suv,pickup, that disregards total number.

Comment: Maybe you want `barplot(t(df))`, if you're trying to visualize the sum across rows?

Comment: I actually wanted to try different things, because I am learning. I actually did `barplot(t(df))` too. Just wanted to see if we can do the same thing without transposing.

Comment: The way to do it without `t()` is to transform the data from "wide" to "long", as explained in the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using `ggplot2` and `reshape2`.
You will need an ID column to track the rows, so I have added that in. I melt the data to long type so that the different groups can be managed and plotted accordingly.
Then plot using `geom_bar`, specifying the row ids as the x axis and the groupings (`fill` and `colour`) for the stack plot and legend.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "car" = c(1,2,4,5,3), "suv" = c(2,3,1,4,1), "pickup" = c(1, 4, 2, 2, 1))
long_df <- df %>% melt(id.vars = c("ID") ,value.name = "Number", variable.name = "Type")

ggplot(data = long_df, aes(x = ID, y = Number)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Type, colour = Type),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "stack")
```

With base R

```
df %>% melt(id.vars = c("ID") ,value.name = "Number", variable.name = "Type") %>% 
  dcast(Type ~ ID, value.var = "Number") %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  barplot()
```

Comment: can we actually perform this just by using base R tools as well? Or ggplot is always necessary?

Comment: Yes, you need to do some fiddling as I understand it, but I have done this and edited the post.
Pretty much anything in Base can be done in `ggplot2` and vice versa. I prefer `ggplot2`, it seems more intuitive and requires less finesse to make the plots pretty. The grammar structuring is also easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(k, v, -row) %>%
    ggplot(aes(row, v, fill = k)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

We use a stacked barplot here, so there is no need to manually calculate the sum. The key here is to transform data from wide to long and keep track of the row.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "car suv pickup
 1   2   1
 2   3   4
 4   1   2
 5   4   2
 3   1   1", header = T)
```